# How to enable MVC scaffolding in WebForms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, webforms

I have an existing ASP.NET WebForms web project in Visual Studio 2013. I am going to migrate this project to ASP.NET MVC in incremental steps and the first step would obvioulsy be to add an MVC controller. I would like to do this using the scaffolding available for normal ASP.NET MVC applications. The scaffolding options are however not available in the Add Project menu. What do I need to do to enable this?

If it isn't possible to enable this, what manual steps do I need to perform in order to add an MVC controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was targeting .NET Framework 4 and it turns out you need to target .NET Framework version 4.5.1 (maybe 4.5 works as well, haven't tried) for the "add scaffolded item" option to be available. So I simply changed the target framework in the properies tab of my web project and the option appeared.